# Are there any tools for reindexing in Elastic 2.0 in Order to Change the Mapping?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a field that I want to be not_analyzed, but it is analyzed (my url field). According to the docs, I can't just delete the mapping anymore now that I am at 2.0.

Are there any existing tools that do this and migrate the data for me if I provide the old and new mapping, or do I have to code this myself?

The mapping as it exists now is as follows in case there are additional gotchas I'm not even considering:

```
{
  "annotate": {
    "mappings": {
      "annotation": {
        "properties": {
          "Category": {
            "type": "string",
            "index": "not_analyzed"
          },
          "CreationUser": {
            "type": "string",
            "index": "not_analyzed"
          },
          "EndDate": {
            "type": "date",
            "format": "strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis"
          },
          "Host": {
            "type": "string",
            "index": "not_analyzed"
          },
          "Id": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "Message": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "Owner": {
            "type": "string",
            "index": "not_analyzed"
          },
          "Source": {
            "type": "string",
            "index": "not_analyzed"
          },
          "StartDate": {
            "type": "date",
            "format": "strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis"
          },
          "Url": {
            "type": "string"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

With this downtime would be acceptable. The index isn't that big anyways.

Comment: From my brief reading of https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/reindex.html it would do something like: Create New Index with new mapping, reindex old index into new index via scrolling, delete old index, rename new index to old index name.

Comment: Oh, 2.3 adds a reindex API https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.3/docs-reindex.html

Answer (score 0):

The npm tool `elasticdump` and `curl` can do this in a pretty straight forward way.

The following is a bit sketchy since it isn't atomic, but it seems to have worked fine:

The new mapping file was just edited JSON from above starting at the object that encloses "mapping".

```
#!/bin/bash
SRC=ny-lselastic01
DST=ny-lselastic01
SRC_INDEX=annotate
DST_INDEX=annotate_temp

#Create new mapping
echo curl -v "http://${SRC}:9200/${DST_INDEX}" --upload-file new_mapping.json

#Migrate Data
echo elasticdump \
  --input=http://${SRC}:9200/${SRC_INDEX} \
  --output=http://${DST}:9200/${DST_INDEX} \
  --type=data

#delete Index
echo curl -X DELETE -v "http://${SRC}:9200/${SRC_INDEX}"

#create new mapping
echo curl -v "http://${SRC}:9200/${SRC_INDEX}" --upload-file new_mapping.json

#Move from temp new
echo elasticdump \
  --input=http://${DST}:9200/${DST_INDEX} \
  --output=http://${DST}:9200/${SRC_INDEX} \
  --type=data
```

Elastic 2.3 has a `_reindex` route that makes this easier (steps are the same in terms of creating the new index with a new mapping, but the `elasticdump` calls can be replaced with calls to `_reindex`. But I had not updated to 2.3 in production yet (but this worked with my local 2.3 dev elastic).

If you use aliases you could do this without deleting the index until after the operation and just switch the alias around.